# Как можно сделать 2 индексные страницы: Приветствие и Главная?

Tags: html

Как можно сделать 2 индексные страницы: Приветствие и Главная? Как в #Facebook. Если пользователь не в системе, то выдать Приветствие. Если в системе, то в обыную заглавную страницу открыть

Comment: Для этого двух страниц не нужно.

    if(данные_в_кукисах_юзера){
      // или
      echo 'Welcome';
      // или редирект на его страницу
   } else {
      echo 'В сад!';
   }

Comment: > Если в системе, то в обыную заглавную страницу открыть

Т.е. залогинен/не залогинен?

Comment: Да, именно

Comment: на чистом html никак :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только с использованием php который и проверяет, залогинен пользователь или нет, и в зависимости от результата выдаст нужный html код